# A Connect Wall to Conquer

Tags: word, knowledge, pattern, connect-wall

The 16 words below may be partitioned into 4 groups.
Additionally, there is a four-letter word which can be placed into all four groups.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ARROW | ATONE | BURN | DEALT |
| DISTRESS | FELT | HIP | LAND |
| MAGMA | MAGNET | POKER | PROFESSOR |
| SAG | SOY | TEA | WOOD |

**Can you identify the four groups?**
**What is the word that can be placed into any group?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This was a tricky one to tie up all the loose ends, but I think I finally have it...

> **...BEAT!**

Each of the connecting groups exhibits:

> a different type of wordplay before you can find the answers.

As follows:

> *Group 1:* DEALT, HIP, MAGMA, TEA
>  **Anagrams of Greek letters**: DELTA, PHI, GAMMA, ETA
>
>  *Group 2:* BURN, FELT, LAND, WOOD
>  **Words that can follow 'HEART' to make a new word**: Heartburn, Heartfelt, Heartland, [Heartwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartwood_(disambiguation))
>
>  *Group 3:* ARROW, MAGNET, PROFESSOR, SAG
>  **[X-Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_X-Men_members) characters missing a letter**: [(M)ARROW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrow_(character)), MAGNET(O), PROFESSOR (X), [SAG(E)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sage_(Marvel_Comics))
>
>  *Group 4:* ATONE, DISTRESS, POKER, SOY
>  **One-word Robert De Niro films with the first letter changed**: [*(S)tone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_(2010_film)), [*(M)istress*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistress_(1992_film)), [*(J)oker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joker_(2019_film)), [*(J)oy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joy_(2015_film))

And the 4-letter word that can fit in all these categories? I told you already!

> It's **BEAT**!
>
>  - An anagram of BETA;
>  - Follows 'HEART' to make 'HEARTBEAT';
>  - Add an 'S' to make the X-Men character BEA(S)T;
>  - Change the first letter to 'H' to make the Robert De Niro film, [*Heat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_(1995_film))

Comment: All correct, really well done!

Comment: @hexomino It was a hard one! My solving order is as presented in the question. The first two groups (and overall answer) fell fairly quickly but the last two took me a lot of head-scratching! :)